# Ambigous redirect done >$2

Tags: shell-script, files, io-redirection

I have finished my bash script but I am still getting two errors. I've also searched for related issues but none worked:

```
#!/bin/bash

avem_element () {
  local e
  for e in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$e" == "$1" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}

i=0
i1=0
# cel de al doilea fisier este dat ca si cel de al doilea argument
while read linie
do
    sir[i++]="$linie"
    echo "L-am citit pe  $linie"
done < $2
# acum procesam primul fisier
i=0
spatiu=" "
virgula=", "
while read linie
do
    sir1[i++]="$linie"
    echo "Am citit  $linie"
    # verificam daca elementul citit este un nume
    if [ avem_element "$sir1[i]" "${sir[@]}" -eq 0 ];then
       sir2[i1++]=$linie$spatiu
    else 
       sir2[i1]=$sir2[i1]$linie
       sir2[i1]=$sir2[i1]$virgula
    fi
done < $2
```

These are the errors:

> ./script.sh: line 16: $2: ambiguous redirect
>
> ./script.sh: line 32: $2: ambiguous redirect

Why am I getting this redirect error and how can I fix it ?

Comment: You should always quote variables: `done < "$2"`. What is the value? It seems you don't check it. `test -z "$2" || ! test -f "$2" && exit 1`

Comment: Thank you for the edit and for the advice. After I quote those variables it tells me `No such file or directory`. I am trying to "play" with two txt files and output something in another .txt. The variables represents the name of the files

Comment: The script needs two arguments so `./script.sh file1 file2` ... is this how you're invoking it ? Then your next problem is at line 26 `[: too many arguments`...

Comment: You're right. I was invoking it in the wrong way and I am also getting that error. How can I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**redirection error**

The problem is that the file you try to read from does not exist because the variable you use to refer to the file is empty.

`$2` means the second parameter but in `./script.sh` there is no parameter at all. You need something like `./script.sh file1 file2`

**if error**

The line

```
if [ avem_element "$sir1[i]" "${sir[@]}" -eq 0 ];then
```

is wrong. If I understand it correctly then you want to call the function `avem_element` with two parameters and compare the exit code. But `[ ]` compares strings only. `if` checks an exit code (often the one of `[  ]`). You don't need `[  ]` at all. Just do this:

```
if avem_element "$sir1[i]" "${sir[@]}"; then
```

Comment: I have two files created under the same directory. There's also the script that should output the result in another file.

Comment: @Alex How do you call that script?

Comment: I did: `chmod +x` then I just did: `./script.sh`

Comment: @Alex `$2` means the second parameter but in `./script.sh` there is no parameter at all. You need something like `./script.sh file1 file2`.

Comment: Yes. I figured it out @Hauke. Look at the upper comments. There is another error.

Comment: @Alex I added the explanation for that.